# [WriteStream]: (c625368) Stream closed with status: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Internal error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have checked all the questions similar to my error but do not have a solid answer.

I'm so confused why I'm getting this error + There is no  writing in Firestore,

I created this simple project to see if there is a problem with my other project code or its Firebase, and it turned out it should be  Firebase setup, I've been having this problem for 2 days

P.s : in my other project which is big project, The Firebase Storage works perfectly but i'm getting the same error as this  below project

My home code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:justatry/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      final user = <String, dynamic>{
        "first": "Ada",
        "last": "Lovelace",
        "born": 1815
      };

// Add a new document with a generated ID
      db.collection("users").add(user).then((DocumentReference doc) =>
          print('DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${doc.id}'));
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue is you are executing the database call in the `setState` call according to the docs of [**`setState`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) :

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for this State object.

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might be associated with the change.

Here's your updated code :

```dart
void _incrementCounter() {
    final user = <String, dynamic>{
        "first": "Ada",
        "last": "Lovelace",
        "born": 1815
      };
    // Add a new document with a generated ID
      db.collection("users").add(user).then((DocumentReference doc) =>
          print('DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${doc.id}'));
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

Here only increment counter action will be passed to the setState method.
Hope it helps .

Links:

- [setState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Comment: Thanks, man,, That was a stupid mistake. thanks for the help